# mpv add moving overlay

Tags: video, object-detection, mpv

I'm using [mpv](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) wrapper [media_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit) to play a video in Flutter app. I created a computer vision car tracker that gives me the information for every frame where the car is located. How could I draw a rectangle around the car and update it every frame?